# Reshape dictionary values from 1D to 2D array

Tags: python, arrays

I want to calculate cosine similarity for words in two dictionaries. The words are keys, arrays are values. In order to do this, I need to convert them to 2D array first, I did some research and found `x = x.reshape(1,-1)` 
I successfully converted it with a single value in dictionary, however, I don't know how to convert the whole dictionary's values by using for loops.

The data

```
D
{'A': array([ 4.80625004e-01, -1.40245005e-01, -9.99999046e-03]),
'B': array([-0.46553   , -0.1519755 ,  0.41836]),
'C': array([0.0090175 ,  0.05817001, -0.09712502])}

D2 (same format as D)
{'D': ([8.11059952e-01,  6.84859991e-01,  1.01619996e-01]),
'E':([-0.82868   ,  0.49513   ,  0.67581]),
'F':([-0.17093   ,  0.88746   ,  0.0931135])}
```

I tried

```
for i in D2.items():
    D2[i] = D2[i].reshape(1, -1) #Error on this line
```

but received error: **TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'**

Some advice please? thank you in advanced!

Comment: Where/how do you define `D2_RESHAPE`?

Comment: it's same as D2, sorry i renamed the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dict.items()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) returns tuples of the key, value pairs. Therefore in your case `i` is a tuple of the key and the value. Try:

```
for i, value in D2.items():
    D2[i] = value.reshape(1, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from numpy import array

d = dict({'A': array([ 4.80625004e-01, -1.40245005e-01, -9.99999046e-03]),
'B': array([-0.46553   , -0.1519755 ,  0.41836]),
'C': array([0.0090175 ,  0.05817001, -0.09712502])})

reshaped_arrays = dict()
    for x, j in d.items():
        dd[x]=j.reshape(1,-1)
```

Comment: This returns a list instead of an array and therefore loses the info about the key.